# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined in App.jsx

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group');

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: ['Item 1...', 'Item 2...', 'Item 3...', 'Item 4...']
        }
        this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
    };
    handleAdd() {
        var newItems = this.state.items.concat([promt('Create New item')]);
        this.setState({ items: newItems });
    }
    render() {
        var items = this.state.items.map(function (item, i) {
            return (
                <div key={item} onClick={this.handleRemove.bind(this, i)}>
                    {item}
                </div>
            );
        }.bind(this));

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>Add Item</button>

                <ReactCSSTransactionGroup
                    transactionName="example"
                    transactionEnterTimeout={500}
                    transactionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                    {items}
                </ReactCSSTransactionGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Your class has no method called `handleRemove`. You're also trying to bind your map function... why?

Comment: As @Galupuf said you has no `handleRemove` method. So you can't bind that method at least you need to create empty method called `handleRemove`

Answer (score 0):

dont know if it helps but I thought this sort of the behaviour you wanted hope it helps, because you execute from **this**.state.items.map you wont have to bind it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import unique from './unique';

class TestDiv extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
this.state={
  items:[
    {text:"textOne"},
    {text:"textTwo"}
  ]
}
}
 handleClick(e,index){
let temp = this.state.items.slice(0);
temp.splice(index,1);
this.setState({
  items:temp
})
}

render() {
let items = this.state.items.map((item,index)=>{
  return(
    <div key={unique.create()} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,index)}>
    <p>{item.text}</p>
    </div>
  )
})
 return (
   <div>
     {items}
   </div>
 )
 }
}

export default TestDiv;
```

Answer (score 0):

First issue: `handleRemove` does not exist on your App class, so you need to create it, and then bind it in the constructor (the same as you have done for `handleAdd`) (see: [bind in constructor, react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#bind-in-constructor-es2015)).

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    ...
    this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
  }
  handleRemove (item) { ... }
}
```

Note: if you are using babel, using the `transform-class-properties` plugin will allow you to use `class properties`, which means you won't need to bind all of your class functions in the constructor (see: [babel class properties plugin, babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)).

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    ...
    this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
  }
  handleRemove (item) { ... }
}

// becomes ...

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    // no bind needed here
  }
  handleRemove = (item) => { ... }
}
```

Second issue: your items are not actually being rendered, so you'll need something like the following:

```
{
  this.state.items.map((item) =>
    <div key={item} onClick={this.handleRemove(item)}>
      {item}
    </div>
  )
}
```

next issue to be aware of: it can cause performance issues to have a function/arrow function/bind inside of render (see: [arrow functions in render, react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render)). The way around this is the extract your item rendering into a separate component, or something like the below:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
    this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
    // initialize your state here
  };

  handleAdd = (value) => { /* logic to add value as an item */ }

  handleRemove = (item) => { /* logic to remove item*/ }

  renderItem = (item) =>
    <div key={item} onClick={this.handleRemove(item)}>
      {item}
    </div>

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.items.map((item) => this.renderItem(item)
        }
        {/* ... other code here */}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```